# change color of font using class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to change the color of font using small square div instead of drop down I can change my font to any color I want using the drop down but I have no idea how to change it using square div is it possible to change color using div squares here are my codes

**Script for drop down**

```js
$("#foo").change(function() {
  //alert($(this).val());
  $('.fid').css("color", $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="foo">
  <option value=" #ab3fdd">purple</option>
  <option value="yellow ">yellow </option>
  <option value="red ">red </option>
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>

<div id="any" class="fid">
  hello world
</div>
```

**This is what I want to use to change color:**

CSS

```
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id=fid>
  <div class="foo blue"></div>
  <div class="foo purple"></div>
  <div class="foo wine"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: menas you want to know how square div color change on drop down selection?

Comment: square div color change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `data-color`. See in [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqvsxkkh/1/)

When you click on square it will take his data color value and you will get your result :), let me know if you have any question.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fid">
  hello world
</div>

<div id="fid" >
  <div class="foo blue" data-color="blue"></div>
  <div class="foo purple" data-color="purple"></div>
  <div class="foo wine" data-color="wine"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}
.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}
.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
    $('.fid').css("color", $(this).attr('data-color'));
});
```

Comment: thank you this is what I was looking for thank you bunch

Comment: Your Welcome, Happy to help you :)

Comment: Check my updated fiddle, you can also use color code instead of his name in data-color..

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go:** Without adding any extra markup.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.foo').on('click', function(){
    $('#any').css('color', $(this).css('background-color'));
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.blue {
  background: #13b4ff;
}

.purple {
  background: #ab3fdd;
}

.wine {
  background: #ae163e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fid">
  <div class="foo blue"></div>
  <div class="foo purple"></div>
  <div class="foo wine"></div>
</div>

<div id="any" class="fid">
  hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would store the color in a data element like so:

```
<div class="foo blue" data-color="blue"></div>
```

In jQuery apply the color to the element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.foo', function() {
  var newColor = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $('.fid').css('color', newColor);
});
```

Comment: so you are saying I can save the color into my database ? and just create a database name called "data-color"

Comment: That is correct. I would use the name dataColor though.

Comment: Thank you for all your help